# Не работает cancelAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript, события, анимация

```
var c = 0;
function movright() {
    c++;
    img.style.top = c + "px";
    requestAnimationFrame(movright);
}
document.onkeydown = function() {
    if(event.keyCode == 40) {
        var k = requestAnimationFrame(movright);
    }
};
document.onkeyup = function() {
    cancelAnimationFrame(k);
}
```

как правильно выполнить cancelAnimationFrame в данном случае?

Comment: написать `var k` в самом начале кода (там же где и `var c`)? А вот присваивание сделать в методе

Answer (score 1):

У вас `onkeyup` не видит переменную `k`

```
let k = 0;

var c = 0;
function movright() {
    c++;
    img.style.top = c + "px";
    k = requestAnimationFrame(movright);
}
document.onkeydown = function() {
    if(event.keyCode == 40) {
        k = requestAnimationFrame(movright);
    }
};
document.onkeyup = function() {
    cancelAnimationFrame(k);
}
```